# Negative margin click should not work

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have a set a negative top margin (-15px) to an image and it works fine. But the problem is the click event. The click is still working just below (i.e. +15px below from the view where exactly image is on the browser) the image. [image]

```
<div data-role="page" >

    <!-- Header -->
    <div data-role="header" class="listHeader" data-position="fixed" data-tap-    toggle="false">

        <img src="images/all_lists_normal.png" class="view_list"> 
        <img src="images/x_normal.png" class="x_image">
        <div class="titleList">
            <p id="page_title" class="label"></p>
        </div>

        <img id="id_new_products" src="images/add_products_normal.png" class="addNewItemImage_page4"> 
        <img id="id_find_stores"  src="images/find_store_normal.png"   class="addNewItemImageMargin">
    </div> <!-- / header -->

    <!-- Content -->
    <div data-role="content" class="mainBackground">
     some content....
    </div>

</div>




.listHeader {
background: url(../images/header_nologo.png) no-repeat 50% 0px;
background-size: 100% 107%;
height: 60px;

}

.view_list {
float: left;
margin-top: 12px;
}

.x_image {
float: right;
margin-right: 15px;
margin-top: 17px;
}

.addNewItemImage_page4 {
min-width: 100%;
margin-top: 9px;
position:relative;
}

.addNewItemImageMargin {
min-width: 100%;
margin-top: -14px; /****************** PROBLEM ***********/
position:relative;
}

.mainBackground {
background: url(../images/background.jpg) no-repeat 50% 0px;
background-size: 100% 100%;
min-height: inherit;
min-width: 100%;
margin-top: -2px;
}
```

JS :-

```
  $("#id_find_stores")
    .click(function(){

        alert('hi');

    });
```

Comment: show your code.

Comment: Most likely, you're not listening for a click on the image but on its wrapper `<div>` or `<whatever>`.  And, yes, we need to see your code to say for sure ;)

Comment: @ahren code is added can u help now...

Comment: please also post your click handler. and you can safely remove `position:relative;`

Comment: I created a JSFiddle to show what it means to put your action handler on the img instead of the wrapping div. http://jsfiddle.net/vhxc3/

Comment: @Calvin An excellent example.... but i'm directly using the click event of the img. I guess ur code is very close can u help me in click event directly on the image ...
Also if u can put the answer in answer section i can accept it ....

Comment: It would be best if you can post your actual click event handler so that we can evaluate what exactly is the problem you face. Otherwise, my assumption is that simply having click handler on image should work as intended. Also, your HTML markup is not very neat and we can't view images as well so we do not know exactly what you are trying to achieve there. Actual screenshot of header would also help

Comment: @ahren already tried relative position.... also i've added the JS

Comment: Got it... i changed the way the layout is drawn using @Calvin example... Calvin can u put ur comment as answer so that i can accept it... thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be an example of placing your action handler on the img instead of the wrapping div:
http://jsfiddle.net/vhxc3/

This would be what I tried to come up with the info you provided us:
http://jsfiddle.net/hhkuL/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#id_new_products').click(function() {
        $(this).css({ "border" : "1px solid red" });            
    }); 
});​
```